# Angular 7 UI will not refresh immediately after array reference has been changed

Tags: angular

I can not get a ngFor list to refresh immediately when I change the reference to the underlying array in a callback. The callback gets called by a database.

In my template I have this:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let todo of todos">
  // Other items here
</ion-item>
```

In my class I have this:

```
Database.addChangeListener(newArray => {
  // This callback gets called, but the UI does not get refreshed.
  // I can see that the underlying array has been changed.
  // The UI only refreshes when I click on it.
  this.todos = newArray;
})
```

I have tried ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush with no luck. I started to look at Observables, but it shouldn't be that difficult to just get a list to refresh when the database has changes, or is it ?

I am guessing that it has something to do with the new array assignment being done in a callback.

What do I need to do to get this to work ?

Comment: `Database.addChangeListener` sounds like it runs outside of Angular. https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some functions, out of performance reasons, run outside of the angular zone, hence the change detection won't detect any changes caused by these methods.
To force execution within the ng zone, try to run the database call inside zone.runTask:

```
Database.addChangeListener(newArray => {
  zone.runTask(() => {
    this.todos = newArray;
  });
});
```

while zone is : NgZone, inject it in the constructor:

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone)
```

[Read more](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

Comment: That did the trick. I ended up just wrapping the one line of code "this.todos = newArray;". It worked either way. Thanks